# Check if variable is computed or stored

Tags: swift, computed-properties

In my app I translate objects from custom classes into dictionaries so that they can be saved locally in a plist as well as on a server. I use the following to turn the properties of a class into a dictionary:

```
func dictionary() -> [String : Any] {

    var count: UInt32 = 0;
    let myClass: AnyClass = self.classForCoder;
    let properties = class_copyPropertyList(myClass, &count);

    var dictionaryRepresentation: [String:Any] = [:]

    for i in 0..<count {
        let property = properties![Int(i)]
        let cStringKey = property_getName(property);
        let key = String(cString: cStringKey!)

        dictionaryRepresentation[key] = self.value(forKey: key) as Any
    }

    return dictionaryRepresentation
}
```

I have a problem, however, with computed properties. It seems that those are computed and the returned value gets put into the dictionary as well, which I would like to avoid. So here is my question:

Is it possible to check whether is a property computed programatically using only its name?

I am assuming this could be possible by trying to assign a value to it which would give me an error or some similar approach.

Comment: [Using Mirror APIs should help](https://appventure.me/2015/10/24/swift-reflection-api-what-you-can-do/). You wouldn't be able to tell stored properties from computed ones, but you would get pretty close by distinguishing settable properties from read-only ones.

Comment: That would be good enough, but after reading through it I am not sure how to make the distinction. I'll have to take a closer look to see. Anyways, thanks for the suggestion, it looks promising.

Comment: Looks like Mirror simply ignores computed properties so that's how to make the distinction, simply go through all the children and they are all settable. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! Consider answering your own question - post an answer with the code fix. Since reflection in Swift is quite different from that in Objective-C, I am sure people will be quite happy to find your answer.

Comment: You just got ahead of me, I had it written up when my internet stopped working, so posting it now.

Comment: Look at Codable for this rather than reflection (in Xcode 9). It's much more powerful, and automatically encodes only stored properties.

Comment: Thanks Rob, once a later beta is out I will definitely look at it, although from a brief look it seems to turn objects into data rather than dictionaries and for my use I need dictionaries.

Comment: You can always write an `Encoder` which converts objects into collections — that's what the base `JSONEncoder` and `PropertyListEncoder` types do at the moment: convert inputs to collections, then pass them off to `JSONSerialization` and `PropertyListSerialization`.

Comment: Well that sounds quite promising. I just want to stay away from Xcode 9 for a while until we get a decent enough beta and then I will definitely see what I can do with he encoders.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, will it be any possibility to get computed values from any other api than Mirror API? I am utilizing Mirror api for most case scenarios, but trying to figure out a way to get computed values which isn't allowed in mirror api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what seems to be a working solution, based on suggestion by `dasblinkenlight`.

Rather than using the Objective-C method outlined above, create a `Mirror` of the class which has a `children` made up of all settable properties, therefore excluding computables.

Used like this:

```
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: MyObject)

for case let (label?, value) in mirror.children {
    print (label, value)
}
```

Here label is the name of the variable and value is obviously the value.

**EDIT:** In case anyone wants to convert objects into dictionary, I am posting the full code here as well. Do however remember that if values are custom objects as well, those will need to be converted too.

```
func dictionary() -> [String:Any] {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)

    var dictionaryRepresentation = [String:Any]()

    for case let (label, value) in mirror.children {

        guard let key = label else { continue }

        dictionaryRepresentation[key] = value
    }

    return dictionaryRepresentation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `property_copyAttributeList(_:_:)` function, it may contain a read-only marker for swift's computed properties. Although I guess `let` properties also will have that marker, so you must find a way to differ them.